# MySQL ORDER BY (DESC|ASC) gets the same result

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

In order to update a table of a tournament in HTML I do the following query:

```
SELECT p.pname, 
       team, 
       won, 
       tie, 
       lost, 
       goals, 
       goalsa 
FROM   player p, 
       stats s 
WHERE  p.tid = s.tid 
       AND p.pname = s.pname 
       AND p.tid = 23 
       AND p.groupno = 'A' 
ORDER  BY s.won, 
          s.tie, 
          ( s.goals - s.goalsa ), 
          s.goals, 
          p.pname DESC
```

Where as the table player has the form

```
player (PName, TID, DraftNo, groupNo, team)
```

and the table stats the form

```
stats(won, tie, lost, goals, goalsA, PName, TID)
```

Currently, in stats there are following entries relevant for the query

```
0    0    0    0    0    a    23
0    0    0    0    0    c    23
0    0    0    0    0    e    23
1    0    0    2    1    g    23
0    0    1    1    2    i    23
```

which means that player g won against player i 2-1.

Now, no matter if I specify the `ORDER BY` option to `DESC` or `ASC`, I'm getting the following result:

```
i    Türkei    0    0     1     1     2
(...) 
g    Italien   1    0     0     2     1
```

which is exactly the opposite of what required. Why is this so? Is there an error in my query? Obviously I want to order the stats from the player with most points to players with less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  DESC or ASC after every field in the sort:

```
ORDER BY s.won DESC, s.tie DESC, ...
```

Comment: As simple as it might sound, but this was indeed the solution that works properly

Comment: But assuming I do not use any DESC or ASC option in the ORDER BY clause, isn't there a standard choosen by the system?

Answer (score 3):

The `ASC` or `DESC` keyword applies only to the column it is placed beside in the `ORDER BY`, so you are doing a descending order by `p.pname` rather than by goals.  You need to apply the `DESC` to `goals` and all other columns which should be sorted higher (`won`)  for example, if you plan to do an aggregate like `SUM(won)`.

```
ORDER  BY s.won, 
      s.tie, 
      ( s.goals - s.goalsa ), 
      s.goals DESC, 
      p.pname
```

A note about your joining method... You are using an implicit inner join, by supplying a comma-separated list in the `FROM` clause and the condition in the `WHERE` clause

```
FROM   player p, 
       stats s 
WHERE  p.tid = s.tid
```

It is recommended to use an explicit `INNER JOIN` instead. The syntax is more modern and often considered easier to read. The two are equivalent functionally and in performance, however.

```
FROM  player p
      INNER JOIN stats s ON p.tid = s.tid
```

Comment: +1. Also worth mentioning to use explicit `JOIN` syntax. Congrats on the 100k

Comment: @njk Thanks and thanks. I'll add the join - I didn't even notice it in there.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, as it is educational at least for me (+1 for that), but the problem was not solved by using your advice.

Comment: @valentinoru Note that I do have advice there about applying the ASC/DESC to all columns where it is relevant.

Comment: That was my mistake, I'm sorry.